# How to install statistics package in Octave(4.0.0) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, octave, statistical

I have tried >> pkg install -forge statistics , but it showed

error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   statistics needs io >= 1.0.18

What should I do now?

Comment: Did you install `octave` from the repo, or from source? if from the repo, you should be able to install the `octave-statistics` package the same way

Comment: I installed octave using [sudo apt install octave] .

Answer (score 11):

I installed octave the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install octave-statistics
```

If you then want to use a function from the statistics package, you will have to use (from the octave prompt):

```
pkg load statistics
```

That worked fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

You should first install io: enter

```
pkg install -forge io
```

on the octave command line.

Then install the statistics package and when you want to use it enter

```
pkg load statistics
```

to load it.